# Cookie not being sent back to the server when making API requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cookies

I'm developing an API in Rails with a React frontend. I'm wiring up the authentication and I'm forgetting something. The first request to /api/v1/me should get a 401, then I authenticate and I get the cookie, but when I make the second request to /api/v1/me, the cookie is not being sent. I made this work in the past but I seem to have forgotten how.

[image]

I'm using Rails 6.0.2.2 on the server and I did try adding this intializer file:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'session', domain: :all
```

and I have enabled CORS with (temporarily):

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it's a CSRF token issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to have `credentials: true` on my CORS setup, so, something like this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "localhost:3000"

    # resource "/api/*", headers: %w[Authorization], methods: :any, expose: %w[Authorization], max_age: 600
    # resource "*", headers: :any, methods: :any
    resource "/api/v1/*",
             headers:     %w[Authorization],
             methods:     :any,
             credentials: true,
             expose:      %w[Authorization],
             max_age:     600
  end
end
```

and I also needed to pass `withCredentials: true` to axios when making the request:

```
axios.get(`${apiEndPoint()}/me`, {withCredentials: true})
```